# Capture output of next method

Tags: r, methods

I'm creating an S3 method for a generic defined in another package. An earlier method for the generic produces some console output that's not returned as part of the function return value, it's only printed to the console. I'd like to capture that output for use in my own method.

I tried using `capture.output()` on `NextMethod()`, but that just results in a bizarre error:

```r
foo <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("foo")
foo.bar <- function(x, ...) cat(x, "\n")
foo.baz <- function(x, ...) capture.output(NextMethod())

foo(structure(1, class = "bar"))
#> 1
foo(structure(1, class = c("baz", "bar")))
#> Error: 'function' is not a function, but of type 8
```

Is this expected behaviour, a known limitation, or a bug? I couldn't find anything matching this error with a quick search.
How can I capture the output of the next S3 method in another S3 method?

Comment: Interestingly this behaviour has changed at some point: As of at least R version 4.2.0, this code no longer produces an error, and works as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is... "expected behavior." I say that because I believe it's technically true, but there's probably no way for a user to expect it necessarily. If you don't care why it happens, but just want to see how to work around it, skip down to the heading "The Fix", because the following explanation of the error is a little involved.

### What does `'function' is not a function, but of type 8` mean?

`type 8` refers to a type 8 `SEXP`. From [Section one of the R Internals Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPs):

> What R users think of as variables or objects are symbols which are
>   bound to a value. The value can be thought of as either a SEXP (a
>   pointer), or the structure it points to, a SEXPREC...
>
> Currently SEXPTYPEs 0:10 and 13:25 are in use....
>
> no    SEXPTYPE    Description
>   ...
>   3 CLOSXP  closures
>   ...
>   8 BUILTINSXP  builtin functions

`NextMethod()` expects a `CLOSXP`, not a `BUILTINSXP`. We can see this if we look at the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/objects.c) (around line 717) of `do_nextmethod()`, the C function underlying `NextMethod()`

```
SEXP attribute_hidden do_nextmethod(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
{
    // Some code omitted
    if (TYPEOF(s) != CLOSXP){ /* R_LookupMethod looked for a function */
        if (s == R_UnboundValue)
            error(_("no calling generic was found: was a method called directly?"));
        else
            errorcall(R_NilValue,
              _("'function' is not a function, but of type %d"),
              TYPEOF(s));
    }
```

So why did that happen here? This is where it gets tricky. I believe it's because by passing `NextMethod()` through `capture.output()`, it gets called using `eval()`, which is a built-in (see `builtins()`).

So how can we deal with this? Read on...

## The Fix

We can simulate capture output with clever use of `sink()`, `cat()`, and `tempfile()`:

```
foo.baz <- function(x, ...) {
    # Create a temporary file to store the output
    tmp <- tempfile("tmp.txt")
    # start sink()
    sink(tmp)
    # call NextMethod() just for the purpose of capturing output
    NextMethod()
    # stop sink'ing
    sink()
    # store the output in an R object
    y <- readLines(tmp)
    # here we'll cat() the output to make sure it worked
    cat("The output was:", y, "\n")
    # destroy the temporary file
    unlink(tmp)
    # and call NextMethod for its actual execution
    NextMethod()
}

foo(structure(1, class = c("baz", "bar")))
# 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if what you saw is documented or not:  the documentation `?NextMethod` makes clear that it isn't a regular function, but I didn't follow all the details to see if your usage would be allowed.

One way to do what you want would be

```
foo.baz <- function(x, ...) {class(x) <- class(x)[-1]; capture.output(foo(x, ...))}
```

This assumes that the method was called directly from a call to the generic; it won't work if there's a third level, and `foo.baz` was itself invoked by `NextMethod()`.